# How to exploit XSS vulnerability through an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, xss

Recently, I found a stored cross site scripting vulnerability in a rather large website, but I am not sure if it is dangerous or worth reporting. On this website, there is a *resource* section that is accessible by logged in users, where they can post certain personal resources that can be used only by themselves. It is not possible to share a resource to another user. Also, there is also a *portfolio* page, where you can make things public. I found two possible vulnerabilities, but I am asking to see if they are dangerous at all.

**Stored XSS** : The first vulnerability includes the *resources* page, where you can post a link. The first time you post the link, it is sanitized, and you cannot get anything useful through. Upon editing the link, though, it is not sanitized, and you can easily insert a `<script>alert(1)</script>` or a `<script>window.location.href="https://google.com"</script>`.

**HTML Injection** : On a different page called *portfolio*, a user can construct a portfolio and add resources. This page does not have the same XSS vulnerability as the previous page, and it is impossible to get javascript execution as far as I know. However, it is possible to insert an iframe into it. The iframe src cannot contain any javascript, but I can make the src lead to my *resources* page (where the stored xss vulnerability is located), to get javascript execution on the public profile page.

**The Problem** : The problem with this vulnerability, is that it only works when *I* view the portfolio page, because the resources page in the iframe is only accessible to *me*. The resource page link is possible to access using only one session cookie (my session cookie) when viewing it. Is there any way that I could pass *my* cookie into the iframe so that the xss vulnerability could be viewed on any user? Is this even a vulnerability / can I make it work? Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you make the iframe `src` point anywhere?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really about programming, but rather brainstorming about potential security vulnerabilities. Even if this question could be answered with code, it's still too broad because it doesn't address a specific issue. You might try [sec.se](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Bergi yes, the src can point anywhere, but it cannot contain javascript

Comment: @p.s.w.g Understandable, but I did tag it with `xss` which involves a lot of brainstorming about possible vulnerabilities, so I believe it is on-topic. Also, as you mentioned, this problem could definitely be answered with code.

Comment: @MichaelHoefler Being able to inject an iframe that contains some malicious page is already a vulnerability worth to report. It might not affect the website itself, but it is dangerous for users of the website.

Comment: @Bergi I will definitely report that, but do you think there is any way to link the page with the logged in xss?

Comment: @MichaelHoefler No, unless you find another vulnerability that lets anyone see your resources page.